# Display SQL Data in a list with check-box

Tags: php, sql, list, checkbox

I am not sure how to go about doing this, but I have an SQL Database where I query for info.  I would like to display the query results in a list on a webpage with a check-box at the beginning so the user can select which they record of info they would like to modify.

My database has over 20+ columns but I only want to display probably 5 columns of data pertaining to the query that I searched for.  Currently I have the data being repopulated in text fields.  But I would like to go a step further and get the data displayed in a horizontal list.

Basically something like this:

Client searches for an order in the database.  Say there are 2 different orders matching the search criteria in the DB.  I would like say 5 columns of data from the DB for those 2 orders displayed on a page with a check-box next to each, so the client can then select which order they want to modify.

I am not sure of the code used to display the sql data in a list with a check-box.  Thanks!

Comment: have you written any code then please paste it and be specific in asking the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below demonstrates how to:

1. Query your database
2. Display it's output in a table with checkboxes beside each entry
3. Submit selected checkboxes to a page
4. Display selection when page reloads

Beware of some parameters that you may need to modify, e.g. database name, username, password, name of the primary key ("id").

```
# connect to mysql
$db_link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$db_link)
    die('Cannot connect : ' . mysql_error());

# select database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('test_db', $db_link);
if (!$db_selected)
    die ('Cannot select database : ' . mysql_error());

# execute search query
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `test_table` LIMIT 20';
$result = mysql_query($sql);

# check result
if (!$result)
    die('Could not successfully run query: ' . mysql_error());

# display returned data
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
        <?php
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>';
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>';
                echo '</td>';
                foreach ($row as $key => $value)
                    echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
}
else
    echo '<p>No data</p>';

# free resources
mysql_free_result($result);

# display posted data
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: This will display all the data in my SQL,  how do I get it to display only what matched what I searched for.  Like when I searched for: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `PropertyInfo` WHERE  `sitestreet` LIKE  '$street'");

Comment: @Jason You can put your own sql query in the `$sql` variable. The one provided in the sample is purely for demonstration.

Comment: @Denis Thanks, I've got it working now with my own sql query.  I am only displaying about 5 fields/columns of data.  When I select the check box next to the order I want, I know how to get the form action to work, but how do I get the data from the one that I checked to carry over to the next page.  I am displaying 5 rows/columns of info, but after I select the order I want and are redirected to a new page, I want all say 40 columns/fields from my DB for that order displayed.  How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @Jason The `id` of each selected row is submitted by the form to the target page. Target page can access the list of submitted `id` via `$_POST['selected']` which would be an array of `id`. All you have to do then is query database for rows with the submitted `id`.

Comment: Ok, so using your code above I have also changed value="'.$row['id'] to value="'.$row['clientreferrance'].  So when I perform my 1st query to search for an order, say it displays 1 order.  I select the checkbox next to that 1 order.  After I hit submit query, and it goes to the Target Page,  what value then do I query or is passed?  Is the clientreferrance for that row passed?  Or what value exactly is stored in ID from the previous page?  I'm having a hard time querying my DB with ID.

Comment: Nvm, I got it figured out and working.  I was missing a ; which was messing up the code.  Appreciate all the help Denis!!! Thanks

Comment: `id` should be replaced with the name of your primary key that uniquely identifies every row. Let say that that key is `clientreferrance`. Now if you replace `$row['id']` with `$row['clientreferrance']`, an array of selected `clientreferrance` values will be submitted to the target page. On a target page, for each submitted value in `$_POST['selected']` you would query for example `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE clientreferrance = '.$_POST['selected'][i]` where `i` is iterating through every element of array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, something like this:

```
$sql = "select primaryKey, field1, field2, ... FROM table"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo <<<EOL;
<form ...>
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Field 1</th>
    <th>Field 2</th>
    ...
</tr>

EOL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_asssoc($result)) {
    echo <<<EOL
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="primaryKey[]" value="{$row['primaryKey']}" /></td>
    <td>{$row['field1']}</td>
    <td>{$row['field2']}</td>
    ...
</tr>

EOL;
}

echo <<<EOL
</table>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

EOL;
```

If you mean list as in `<select>`, then the basic logic works the same, just adjust the html to output a `<select>` and a series of `<option>`'s as desired.